# Discord.js -- make presenceUpdate send a message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

im trying to get my super simple bot to send a message stating the user status. as if someone is offline, online,..etc it automatically sends a message to the server saying that happened.
im just doing a work around so it can get updated (i know i need to !status everytime)

anyone has an idea to make it send the same message instantly after `presenceUpdate` fires?

```
let userStatus = [];

bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let username = newMember.user.username;
    let status = newMember.user.presence.status;
    userStatus.push(username, status);
    console.log(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.user.presence.status}`);
})

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    // if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if (console.log())
        let [username, status] = userStatus;

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "status")) {
        let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription("Status Update")
            .setColor("#FFF")
            .addField('.............................................', `${username} is now ${status}`);

        message.channel.send(botembed);

        userStatus = [];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think you're running into is that you don't have a direct reference to a channel anymore, which is why you can't "easily" call `<TextChannel>.send(...)`. You'll have to decide which channel you want to send a message to, in your `presenceUpdate` event listener. Once you decide, you can use this code to get a reference to that channel using the channel's `name`:

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    // get a reference to all channels in the user's guild
    let guildChannels = newMember.guild.channels;

    // find the channel you want, based off the channel name
    // -> replace '<YOUR CHANNEL NAME>' with the name of your channel
    guildChannels.find('name', '<YOUR CHANNEL NAME>')
        .send('test message!')
        .then(msg => {
            // do something else if you want
        })
        .catch(console.error)
});
```

Note: you don't have to use the channel's `name` property to identify a unique channel, you can use the channel's `id` by doing

```
guildChannels.get('<YOUR CHANNEL ID')
.send('...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. i didn't know much to figure that out.